# FQL giving NoIndexFunctionException even though when column is indexable

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am performing user login using `LoginButton`, provided in Facebook SDK, in my app and later on i am using the following `FQL` to retrieve all pages that have Sherlock in their keywords.

```
SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE  keywords = 'Sherlock'
```

But if gives me the following exception

```
Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql
```

even though `keywords` column is indexable as show on 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page.

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could anyone please explain why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this : [Facebook bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465142486885975?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5284c2fdd0df13717065427)

It's a bug "assigned".
So you are not doing something wrong, just Fql documentation not updated.

If you try :[Graph Api exemple](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=173740740766?fields=keywords,about)
you can see that I add "Keywords" as field but no response.

I think it's over for "keywords" on page table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have already started using `Request` and `GraphObject`.